# Does `Async.StartImmediate` run the `async` process on the same thread throughout the lifetime of the process?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

This is in reference to F#'s [`Async.StartImmediate`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#StartImmediate) method. Possibly a diversion, but this method is confusingly named because `Async.Start` *also* starts the `async` process immediately, just on a thread pool.

Anyway, the documentation states that `Async.StartImmediate` starts the process using the calling thread. Does the `async` process continue to execute on that same thread throughout the lifetime of the process? Or is it possible it switches at some point? To my knowledge, `Async.Start` allows the process to switch underlying threads since it runs on top of a thread pool.

Edit: To clarify the question, I am thinking about an `async` that doesn't contain any other usage of `async`, `let!`, `do!`, `return!`, etc. for example:

```ml
async { printfn "testing" }
```

Comment: My understanding is that it runs initially in the same thread, but then of course, depending on what do you do inside the async it can end up running in a different one.

Comment: @Gus That's a good point. I updated the question to rule out other asynchronous behavior inside the `async`.

Comment: @Gus I ended up doing some experiments and reading and posted this in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As you already found, the difference is that `StartImmediate` runs the *prefix* on the current thread while `Start` switches immediately. To get an actual continuation, you need a "real"* async operation, e.g. `Async.Sleep`. `async { }` by itself is *not* async but lets you *use* async. That is, the difference is visible with

```
open System.Threading

Thread.CurrentThread.Name <- "Main"

let computation s = async {
    printfn "async prefix %s: %s" s Thread.CurrentThread.Name
    do! Async.Sleep 1
    printfn "async continuation %s: %s" s Thread.CurrentThread.Name
}

computation "StartImmediate" |> Async.StartImmediate
computation "Start" |> Async.Start
```

which prints

> async prefix StartImmediate: Main 
> async prefix Start: .NET ThreadPool Worker 
> async continuation StartImmediate: .NET ThreadPool Worker 
> async continuation Start: .NET ThreadPool Worker

Note that the two operations are interleaved now and the continuation is run on the thread pool in both cases.

*** Update on "real" async**

What do I mean by "real" async? `async` is *essentially* a way to write "Here is some code, run that, if you encounter IO, go do something else and once the OS signals 'done' continue the remaining work." Now, as long as there is no IO (reading/writing from/to a file, stream, DB, waiting for a timer, ...) the current thread (in `do!`, `Async.StartImmediate`) will run the "prefix" code (potentially all code including inner `do! async {`). Once a "real" async operation is encountered, the "continuation" (the code after the IO operation) is scheduled and the former thread is free to do something else. Once the operation is completed the continuation is executed on the thread pool.

That is except for UI programs (WPF, WinForms, ...) where it is oftentimes desirable to run the continuation on the original thread (UI), because only that is allowed to write to the UI respectively shared data structures. In order to make that happen there needs to be a [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=net-6.0) and some kind of event loop (the original thread needs to check whether there's work waiting).

In practice it is more complicated due to (amongst others) C# having 'hot' (already running) `Task`s, F# cold (reusable) `async`s and both being used also for parallelism (CPU bound work distributed across multiple cores).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think this is what I was missing: "To get an actual continuation, you need a real async operation, e.g. `Async.Sleep`. `async { }` by itself is not async but lets you use async." But I am still confused. Haha. I thought `async { }` returned an `Async` value. What about it is not a "real" async operation? Thanks again for the elaborations. I'm just trying to better understand and predict thread behavior for async stuff.

Comment: @bmitc I added a bit of explanation, feel free to ask follow up questions if the are closely related... otherwise a new question might be better.

Answer (score 2):

I did an experiment that seems to imply that `Async.StartImmediate` does indeed propagate down to contained `async` processes.

```ml
// async.fsx
let outerAsync = async {
    printfn "Outer async thread: %A" System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name
    do! async {
        printfn "Inner async thread: %A" System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name
    }
}

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name <- "main thread"
printfn "Main thread: %A" System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name

printfn "Async.StartImmediate"
Async.StartImmediate outerAsync

printfn "Async.Start"
Async.Start outerAsync
```

Then running this:

```
PS > dotnet fsi .\async.fsx
Main thread: "main thread"
Async.StartImmediate
Outer async thread: "main thread"
Inner async thread: "main thread"
Async.Start
Outer async thread: ".NET ThreadPool Worker"
Inner async thread: ".NET ThreadPool Worker"
```

Regarding if the computation *stays* on the thread, I found this in *Expert F# 4.0* for `Async.StartImmediate`:

> Starts the async computation on the current thread. It will run on the current thread until the first point where a continuation is scheduled for the thread; for example, at a primitive asynchronous I/O operation.

It further says:

> This starts an async computation using the current thread to run the prefix of the computation. For example, if you start an async computation from a GUI thread, the prefix of the computation will run on the GUI thread.

I am not entirely sure what *exactly* "until the first point where a continuation is scheduled for the thread" or "the prefix of the computation" mean in terms of knowing when the `async` process will jump from the current thread, but this is the most information I could find.

Comment: There‘s no „point where a continuation is scheduled“ as there‘s no async operation involved. Try adding e.g. `do! Async.Sleep(1)` before the inner printf.

Comment: @CaringDev I'm not sure I understand though. What's the difference between that `do!` and the `do!` that runs the inner `async`? It is only the outer `async` that is started immediately in both cases. In one case, the thread that the most outer `async` was run on "propagates", and in the other, it doesn't. I don't see why `do! async { ... }` behaves differently than `do! Async.Sleep(1)`.

Comment: I added an answer to explain the difference